# Compile ERROR: The method error(String, Object, Object) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, slf4j

I inherited a project that is not in Maven & has no documentation on dependency set up.  I'm getting A LOT of errors related to slf4j.

For example, the  _logger.error() call in the following code generates this compile error: "The method error(String, Object, Object) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments".

```
import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//lines ommitted

Logger _logger; 

//lines ommitted
    _logger.error("getValueList|Error|valueId|{}|date|{}| current|{}|", _valueId, _date,_current);
```

What slf4j jars do I need to include in my class path to avoid this?  Note, I already have all of slf4j 1.7.5 in my classpath & most logging statements compile fine, but others do not.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

UPDATE - added  extra code for clarity

Comment: Well ... What type does `_logger` have?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I would imagine it has type Logger judging by the compile error

Comment: Logger _logger;  With import org.slf4j.Logger; &  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; as imports

Comment: @jthomas There are so many logging frameworks with even more `Logger` types. Look at OP's answer for my question. He uses `org.slf4j.Logger`.

Comment: Are you sure the 3 additional parameters are Objects and not for instance int or long?

Comment: _valueId is Integer, _date is Timestamp, _current is Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:  I accidently included slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar in the classpath.  That was being linked instead of slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar.  Once I removed slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar the slf44 compile errors went away.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to this link http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html
As per the doc, there is no way to include 3 arguments in the logger.error method the way your code is doing.
The only way to involve more than two Objects for logging is by putting those objects in an array and passing it as parameter to the logger.error method

Refer to

void error(String format,
           Object... arguments)

method on the page

Comment: The varargs works also when passing comma separated parameters

Comment: See my answer.  I think varargs was added in 1.7.x.  Therefor my mistaken addition of 1.6.6 to the classpath caused the issue.